# twitter4j - controlling sampling rate

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I need to crawl the tweets related to a particular query for last 1 week using twitter4j library. I have written a bulk-collection-batch-restartable program that I ran overnight to collect around 5 GB of tweets. I believe these are sampled at 1% by Twitter API.
I need the tweets spanning over the week, but this is huge amount of data for me. I just need the tweets that are just representative of the last week. I was wondering if is there any way I can control the sampling rate through twitter4j configuration.

Comment: I really appreciate if you comment explaining the reason for down-voting the question. Is there anything incorrect or not clear in the question?

Comment: You can't decrease the sample rate, you should make an approach that satisfy you, like taking 10% of the random tweets recollected on an hour or using some filters... whatever you like!

Comment: Yes. That's how I implemented it. Thank you for the reply. You may add it to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't decrease the sample rate, you should make an approach that satisfy you, like taking 10% of the random tweets recollected on an hour or using some [filters](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html#filter-twitter4j.FilterQuery-)... whatever you like!